# How to throw an error message if id field exist in POST request in Mulesoft 4

Tags: anypoint-studio, mulesoft

How to check if id in post request should not be included.
I have 2 scenarios.

request body:

```
 {
    "name"="John"
 }
```

Expected result:

"Success"

request body:

```
 {
    "id"="323",
    "name"="Jane"
 }
```

Expected result:
"id field should not be specified."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will help you with what you are looking for

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
{
    output: 'ID field should not be specified' 
    when payload.id? otherwise 'Success'
}
```

[image]

[image]

in mule 4: when otherwise has been replaced with if else.
here is the dataweave code

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---

if (payload.id?)
  { result: "ID field should not be specified" }
else { result: "Success" }
```

[image]

Comment: ammended my answer with an example from mule 4. please check